# Windows Service or ASP.Net+BackgroundService for REST API and infinite running background process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-services

I want to design an application that serves a REST API and also has a continuous process running that connects to websockets and processes the incoming data.

I have two approaches in mind:

1. Create a Windows Service with Kestrel running on one thread and the websocket listener on another. The API would be made accessible via a IIS reverse proxy.
2. Create the REST API with ASP.NET directly hosted in IIS and utilize the BackgroundService Class for the websocket listener as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

As I am new to the Windows Ecosystem I'd like to know if one of the approaches is more suitable or if I'm going about it the wrong way.

My understanding is that the Windows service approach should just work, but it seems more elaborate.
I'm unsure about the BackgroundService approach. The background process should really run 24/7. Are BackgroundServices designed for this? The docs always talk about long running tasks, but does it also work for infinite running ones with restart on failure etc.?

Comment: The latter can be quite problematic if you check out similar solutions like Hangfire, https://halfblood.pro/unpleasant-facts-about-hangfire-632a3228ff8a

Comment: Markus is right. App pool on IIS will be recycle at specific time or reach a performance bottleneck. So host the continuous process is a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to host the continuous process in a Windows service as you have much more control over the lifecycle.
With a BackgroundService hosted on IIS, the process is controlled by IIS. In this case, it might be recycler from time to time or terminated of idle for some time. You can control this behavior with some configuration settings, but especially in combination with ASP.NET Core, the IIS process might be running, but the underlying Kestrel service is only started when a request hits the website.

If the two components do not rely on each other, you could also split them and have the best of both worlds, the web application hosted in IIS and the websocket listener running in a Windows service